# Are rational functions the only functions that are preserved by field automorphisms?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, rational-functions

I am reading Allufi's Algebra: Chapter 0 and I tried to think about what makes polynomials so important to field extensions. I realised part of the reason is the fact that if $L/K$ is a field extension, $f(x) \in K[x]$ is a polynomial and $\varphi \in Aut_K L$ is a K-automorphism of L, then $\varphi (f(x))=f( \varphi (x))$, i.e. polynomials are preserved by K-automorphisms. Obviously, rational functions are another type of function for which it is true, but I'm wondering whether those are the only possibilities, or are there any other functions which are preserved by K-automorphisms.

Comment: Any automorphism of $K$ will be preserved by a $K$-automorphism; so for example, complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is preserved by any $\mathbb{C}(x)$-automorphism of an extension $L$.

Comment: But the reason polynomials are important for field extensions is that they yield one of the two types of extensions (and the more interesting one): the algebraic extensions.